# The determinanat of the matrix is coming zero

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, determinants

I am trying to find the determinant of the matrix M which is constructed using 12 equations. But when I took determinat. It is coming as zero. The matrix is symbolic in nature. I have used sympy package to construct the matrix M. The possible out is an analytical expression which is a function of `a,b,z1,z2,l,L,g`

```
from sympy import *
from numpy.linalg import matrix_rank

b,g,l,a,L,z1,z2,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,d1,d2,d3,d4,x,y = var('b g l a L z1 z2 
c1 c2 c3 c4  c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12 d1 d2 d3 d4  x y')

#beam equation

W1= c1*cos(b*x) + c2*sin(b*x) + c3*cosh(b*x) + c4*sinh(b*x)
W2= c5*cos(b*(x - z1)) + c6*sin(b*(x - z1)) + c7*cosh(b*(x - z1)) + c8*sinh(b*(x - z1))
W3=c10*sin(b*(x - z2)) + c11*cosh(b*(x - z2)) + c12*sinh(b*(x - z2)) + c9*cos(b*(x - z2))


#Boundary conditions on beam

e1=W1.subs(x,0)
e2=diff(W1, x).subs(x,0)
e3=diff(W1, x,2).subs(x,1)
e4=diff(W1, x,3).subs(x,1)


#bar equation
U1=d1*cos(L*y) + d2*sin(L*y)
U2=d3*cos(L*y) + d4*sin(L*y)

print(U2)

# Boundary conditions on bar*)
e5 = U1 .subs( y, 0);
e6 = (U1 .subs( y, g)) - (W1 .subs( x, z1));

e7 = U2 .subs( y, 0);
e8 = (U2 .subs( y, g)) - (W2 .subs( x, z2));

eqns = [e5,e6, e7, e8]
ss=linsolve(eqns, [d1,d2, d3, d4])

ss=list(ss)[0]

dd1=ss[0]
dd2=ss[1]
dd3=ss[2]
dd4=ss[3]

U1=U1.subs([(d1,dd1),(d2,dd2)])
U2=U2.subs([(d3,dd3),(d4,dd4)])


#Compatability conditions
e9= (W1.subs( x, z1)) - (W2.subs(x, z1))
e10=(diff(W1, x).subs(x,z1))-(diff(W2, x).subs(x,z1))

e11=(W2.subs( x, z2)) - (W3.subs(x, z2))
e12=(diff(W2, x).subs(x,z2))-(diff(W3, x).subs(x,z2))


#equlibrium equation

e13=(diff(W1, x,3).subs(x,z1))+(a*(diff(U1, y).subs(y,g)))-(diff(W2, x,3).subs(x,z1))

e14=(diff(W1, x,2).subs(x,z1)) + (diff(W2, x,2).subs(x,z1))

e15 =(diff(W2, x,3).subs(x,z2))+(a*(diff(U2, y).subs(y,g)))-(diff(W3, x,3).subs(x,z2))

e16 =(diff(W2, x,2).subs(x,z2)) + (diff(W3, x,2).subs(x,z2))


eqnlist=[e1,e2,e3,e4,e9,e10,e11,e12,e13,e14,e15,e16]
varibles=[c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12]
  
M, B = linear_eq_to_matrix(eqnlist,varibles)

M.det()
```

Comment: When I run the above I get `simplify(M.det()) = b**18*(32*cos(b)*cosh(b) + 32)`.

Comment: I'm getting the same result (sympy 1.8).  Also note that you shouldn't import from `numpy.linalg`, as numpy and sympy functions don't mix well.

Comment: I am still getting zero. what changes should I have to do? Another question the matrix M depends on `b,z1,z2, g`  and `a`, how come the results do not have those terms? I  cross-checked this in Mathematica, the determinant function depends upon the above-mentioned variables.